# I couldn't build Jhipster sample app

Tags: eclipse, maven, jhipster

I'm trying to run Jhipster sample app in my Eclipse kepler . I've downloaded the project from [here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app) and I've imported it as existing maven project but it couldn't be build . I got this exception :

**The type java.util.Optional cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    AccountResource.java**

and many **"Undefined CSS file"** errors

how can I run this project in my Eclipse ?

Comment: `java.util.Optional` is in Java 8, are you using Java 8?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should create your application using the [yeoman generator](http://yeoman.io/generators/). Install yeoman and execute `yo jhipster` from your command line.

Answer (score -3):

a)For the java exception basically you need to remove the old version of java from your build path and add support for java 8.

You need to follow these steps

```
1) Right-click on project » Properties » Java Build Path
2) Select Libraries tab 
3) Find the JRE System Library and remove it 
4) Click Add Library... button at right side » Add the JRE System Library(Workspace default JRE)
```

Do not forget to set the Java jdk compiler compliance level to 1.8 (Preference -> Java -> compiler )

b) The jhipster site mentions about the configuration settings(css,javascript and html etc)for eclipse to avoid errors in eclipe. https://jhipster.github.io/configuring_ide_eclipse.html